# Access 2016: Deduplicating code in a reverse crosstab query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm trying to write a Access 2016 query that will convert a flat table

`ID |Date   |Site Name  | Alexandrium   | Ceratium  | etc etc`

... Into a multirow table:

`ID |Date   |Site Name  | Species   | Num`

I've been able to do this, but the query is extremely long: I've got 20 values/columns for each species, and I have to write out a UNION query for each and every species name:

```
    SELECT ID, Date, [Site Name], "Alexandrium" as Species, Alexandrium as Num
        FROM DatabaseName
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ID, Date, [Site Name], "Ceratium" as Species, Ceratium as Num
        FROM DatabaseName
    UNION ALL
```

Et cetera, et cetera.

Is there a better way to do this, where one can feed the query a list of column names and it will iterate over them, execute queries, and UNION them all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to provide a sample of the source data, that way we may think of how to get there from here.

Answer (score 0):

Access doesn't have an easy way to unpivot like SQL Server does.

If you have the list of names and don't want to write out the SQL you can feed it into a query like so:

```
SELECT "SELECT ID, Date, [Site Name], '" & [SpeciesName]
& "' as Species, " & [SpeciesName] & " as Num FROM DatabaseName UNION " AS Expr1
FROM Species
```

Then copy the results, remove the last UNION and paste the SQL into a query